# Dynamically created divs get hidden after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have several divs in a nested gridview which are bound to att runtime with the command div id="div<%# Eval("id") %>". I then set the visibilty of the div via javascript. The problem is that the visibilty setting isnt retained between postbacks. (Im using a filter feature that filters the rows in the nested gridview).

How can I retain the visibilty settings for all the divs created dynamically? (Could be up to fifty divs.)

Comment: for the sake of people with issues with sight please dont use the visibility settings on divs, some screen readers have issues and will not read things when their visible state is changed in a div tag, this means you stop people with sighted issues from being able to use your webpage. please use css and absolute position of -99999 then bring it into visible sight when needed :)
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/accessibilityseo-friendly-css-hiding/

Answer (score 1):

If you are making the divs visible with javascript, when you postback they dont save their current state. However, you could make an ajax call to update the database with their current state each time you change the state with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not meaningful to store the div's state in the DB: Store which divs have been set visible/invisible in a asp:hiddenfield. Then when the page reloads, reset the div's visible state.

Comment: though this is not compliant to the w3 web accessibility guidelines, restricts some disabled users from using the service which, while not illegal, is frowned upon as it can easily be bypassed to give a fair experience for all users

Comment: This will work depending on the situation. If you are wanting people to be able to postback, you may very well want them to be able to leave the page and come back.